# Autoregressive model and shock events

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to model `steel` prices using `brent` prices with following model:

$steel_t=\alpha + \beta steel_{t-1}+\gamma brent_t + \epsilon_t$

I have monthly data. I fitted the parameter values with `lm` (R, is that reasonable?).  Now I want to see the effect of a "shock event" in one year, e.g. what happens to steel prices  if brent prices go to USD 50 in one year (it is about USD 100 nowadays). How can I do it? Does it make sense to use an autoregressive model for such analysis?

Comment: prices are usually unit-root processes. Did you check for that? If they are unit-root, your regression might not make sense.

Comment: how good is your fit?

Comment: @RockScience seems to be good (t-test and F-test). Adjusted R-squared =0.97 (I believe its value does not make sense here).@mpiktas I did a test with 'adf.test' from tseries package: _p=0.43 alternative:stationary_, which means (if I correctly interpreted) that it contains an unit-root...

Comment: if you have unit roots in general you should fit VECM.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest using the `arima` function instead and explicitly fitting a AR(1) model. I don't think it will change your result, but it should properly handle the error correlations.

Once you have that, you can set up your predicted values of `brent` and just run the model on that.